# Reverse Enggineering android application

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer my own application with apktool. After decompiling i can't able to see my pacakage name in smali folder. In res folder all files are visible. Following is the build config i've useed,

```
minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting: "true"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smali files are created by decompiling **DEX** (Dalvik Executables). I don't know why you are searching for your package name in it but you can't decompile the smali file into java source. If you want the java source then use a different method to decompile.

You can use dex2jar and JdGui Google it you will find.
1.Rename your APK to .zip extension.
2.open it and find classes.dex
3.use dex2jar to decompile the Dex files to jar.
4.open the decompiled jar file with jdGui.
You will find your package and source there.

Note: if you used multidex= true then you will find multiple dex files in your APK.